# Make dock visible at Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: dock, dconf, editor

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS a few weeks and doing some modifications at Wayland, I just want to know if there's one way to put dock-fixed in fullscreen mode without "push" windows to up, like image below.

[result expected with brave-browser in full-screen mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7cKF.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can install `Dconf Editor` in the snap store and activate auto hide in full screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0YYV.png